# Find a instance by field value comparison in Seq

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

What is best practice to get a instance in Seq ?

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
val points: Seq[Point] = Seq(Point(1, 10), Point(2, 20), Point(3, 30))
```

I'd like to acquire Point with the maximum of y. (in this case: `Point(3, 30)`)

What's best way ?

Comment: if one of the answers provided solves your problem, please accept it to close the issue. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use [`TraversableOnce.maxBy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce@maxBy[B](f:A=%3EB):A):

```
val points: Seq[Point] = Seq(Point(1, 10), Point(2, 20), Point(3, 30))

scala> points.maxBy(_.y)
res1: Point = Point(3,30)
```

Answer (score 4):

@YuvalItzchakov's answer is correct but here another way to do it using [Ordering](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0-M2/index.html#scala.math.Ordering) :

```
val points: Seq[Point] = Seq(Point(1, 10), Point(2, 20), Point(3, 30))
// points: Seq[Point] = List(Point(1,10), Point(2,20), Point(3,30))

val order = Ordering.by((_: Point).y)
// order: scala.math.Ordering[Point] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$9@5a2fa51f

val max_point = points.reduce(order.max)
// max_point: Point = Point(3,30)
```

or

```
points.max(order)
// Point = Point(3,30)
```

or with `implicit` `Ordering`:

```
{
  implicit val pointOrdering = Ordering.by((_: Point).y)
  points.max
}
// Point = Point(3,30)
```

**Note**: [`TraversableOnce.maxBy`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce@maxBy[B](f:A=%3EB):A) uses also implicit Ordering. [Reference](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L234).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is by using foldleft.

```
val points:Seq[Point] = Seq(Point(1,10),Point(2,20),Point(3,30))
points.foldLeft[Point](Point(0,0)){(z,f) =>if (f.y>z.y) f else z}
```